# Splash Screen Disappearing

Tags: vbscript, splash-screen, hta

I have found some code for a splash screen but I need to fix one problem:

When I run my HTA program the splash screen pops up as normal. But if I click onto my desktop the splash screen goes away, is there any way to fix this problem?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Splash Screen</title>
  <script type="text/vbscript">
  Dim oPopup
  Set oPopup = window.createPopup()

  Function goContext()
    Dim oPopupBody
    Set oPopupBody= oPopup.document.body
    oPopupBody.innerHTML = oContext.innerHTML
    call oPopup.show(275, 200, 400, 300, document.body)
  End Function
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="goContext()" onmousedown="oPopup.hide">
  <!-- Splash Screen -->
  <div ID="oContext" style="display:none" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
            <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:400px; height:300px; border:1px solid black; background:#eeeeee;" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
      <div style="padding:20px; background:white; border-bottom:5px solid #cccccc" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
        <b onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false"><h2 align="center"><i>Game Launcher </i><small><sub>ver: 1.00</sub></small></h2></b>
      </div>
      <div style="padding:20px; font-size:8pt; line-height:1.5em; font-family:verdana; color:black;" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
        <center onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
          <marquee DIRECTION="UP" HEIGHT="100" WIDTH="300" SCROLLAMOUNT="1" onselectstart="return false">Le text goes here</marquee>
          <br /><br />
          <b>&#169;2013 Petzl11 Development.</b>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <center>
    <button onclick="goContext()">Show Splash Screen</button><br>
    <b>Internet Explorer Only!</b>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I originally wanted to make, but this one you helped me with is perfect, this one below is .vbs:
[Here](http://pastebin.com/drW5Zz8b) is the link

Comment: When you look at the code, what do you think makes the splash screen go away? (Also, edit your question. You did not even say what exactly is the problem for you.)

Comment: I'm not to sure why it goes away :/ I'm new to vbs.

Comment: Yes, but try to read through the code line-by-line. There is a single spot that should be instantly suspicious to you.

Comment: Would this be it?
    <body onload="goContext()" onmousedown="oPopup.hide">

Comment: Yes. What happens if you remove/rename the `onmousedown` attribute?

Comment: Removing it does not help so I think I need to rename it?

Comment: Should I try to rename it to oPopup.show?

Comment: Removing it is as good as renaming it. Okay, then that's not it... Next try to add the missing double quote `"` after the `style` attribute on the `<div style="position:absolute; ...` line.

Comment: Not related, but when you've a HTA, you could put `<HTA:application selection="no"/>` to the `head`. You'd get rid of all those repeated inline handlers (`onselectstart`, `ondragstart` and `oncontextmenu`). Works well when HTA is run in IE<10 document mode.

Comment: Would it look like this <div style="position:absolute;..."

Comment: @Petzl11 Not quite right. Look at the other attributes. They all work the same. Double quotes must be balanced (just like parentheses).

Comment: Oh, so I need to do this <div style="position:absolute;"...

Comment: Correct, but include all the style definitions, not just `position`. (You also still did not say what you actually *want* to happen.)

Comment: Now you confused me :/

Comment: Could you please elaborate more, sorry, i'm a noob

Comment: Compare that `style` attribute with the other ones. Where do all attributes have their opening double quotes and where the closing ones? Look closely. You'll notice a difference.

Comment: I updated it, i think i fixed it?

Comment: Yes, that looks better. Does it work?

Comment: Somewhat, but the majority of it is fixed, By the way, are you a teacher? Because you are rely good at this :D See you around :D

Comment: No, I'm not a teacher. I've just been around this site since forever. I've added an answer that makes a few other improvements, like @Teemu suggested.

Comment: Thank you, you should be a Teacher, you are rely patient.

Comment: Only on good days. ;) But at least you've learned that attention to detail is absolutely necessary to get anywhere in development. Also: Using an editor that supports syntax highlighting is absolutely necessary. If you are working in Notepad currently stop immediately and use, at least, [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html). Things like a missing double quote are much more easily noted when you have code colors.

Comment: Okay, I will download Notepad2, thanks again, you where very helpful :D See you around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code, after some interactive debugging (a style attribute was not closed correctly).

```html
<html>
<head>
  <HTA:APPLICATION selection="no" contextmenu="no" />
  <title>Splash Screen</title>
  <script type="text/vbscript">
  Dim oPopup
  Set oPopup = window.createPopup()

  Function goContext()
    Dim oPopupBody
    Set oPopupBody= oPopup.document.body
    oPopupBody.innerHTML = oContext.innerHTML
    call oPopup.show(275, 200, 400, 300, document.body)
  End Function
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="goContext()" onmousedown="oPopup.hide">
  <!-- Splash Screen -->
  <div ID="oContext" style="display:none">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:400px; height:300px; border:1px solid black;background:#eeeeee;">
      <div style="padding:20px; background:white; border-bottom:5px solid #cccccc">
        <b><h2 align="center"><i>Game Launcher</i> <small><sub>ver: 1.00</sub></small></h2></b>
      </div>
      <div style="padding:20px; font-size:8pt; line-height:1.5em; font-family:verdana; color:black;">
        <center>
          <marquee direction="up" height="100" width="300" scrollamount="1">Le text goes here</marquee>
          <br><br>
          <b>&#169;2013 Petzl11 Development.</b>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Splash Screen -->
  <center>
    <button onclick="goContext()">Show Splash Screen</button><br>
    <b>Internet Explorer Only!</b>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the `<HTA:APPLICATION>` element and [read through its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).